# Ionic retrieve custom headers parameter from an http.get

Tags: ionic-framework, http-headers

As the title explains, I pretend to retrieve in `console.log` a custom header named "count" inside a `map` from an `http.get` request. The browser shows that the count value exists. How can I retrieve that value?

[image: Example of the Response Headers in the browser]

This is what I have tried, the problem is that this returns `null`.

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http";  
constructor (public http: Http) {}
myFunction() {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map((response: Response) => {
          console.log(response.headers.get('count')); // returns null
       });
}
```

`response.headers` only gets this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it adding `count` to the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` on the website that provides the service.

```
# Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
exposedHeaders: ['count']
```